# Can I rewrite to a redirected URL using .htaccess file?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, url-rewriting

I have a page A.

I want to have a page B which is served as a rewrite of page A using `.htaccess`.

Is it possible to redirect page A to page B from `.htaccess` or is it going to go into an endless loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly do this. However, you do need to be careful of endless redirect/rewrite loops, as you suggest.

You need to use mod_rewrite in `.htaccess`. Although, exactly how you implement this can depend on your specific scenario and other directives you may already have in your `.htaccess` file(s).

In order to prevent a redirect loop, you typically want to make sure that the *external* "redirect" from Page A to page B only happens for direct requests (ie. requests the user has made) and not requests that have been internally rewritten by your own directives in `.htaccess`.

Commonly this is done by either:

- Check the requested URL against `THE_REQUEST` server variable. This contains the first line of the request header and contains the full (encoded) URL-path and query string. For example:

  ```
  GET /PageA.html HTTP/1.1
  ```

  This does not change throughout the request (ie. is not changed when the request is internally rewritten).
- OR, check the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable, which is empty on the initial request and contains "200" (as in `200 OK` HTTP response status) after the first successful rewrite. This is arguably *cleaner* than checking `THE_REQUEST` in most cases.
- Alternatively, you can use the `END` flag (Apache 2.4+), instead of `L` (`last`) on the *internal rewrite* to stop all processing, preventing the rewrite engine to start over and retesting the earlier redirect. However, this may not work if you have other rewrites.

For example:

Given that `/PageA.html` is the underlying filesystem path that serves the page and `/PageB` is the URL the user sees then, in the following order:

1. Externally "redirect" any direct requests for `/PageA.html` to `/PageB`
2. Internally "rewrite" any request for `/PageB` to `/PageA.html`.

In `.htaccess`, using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

# 1. Redirect direct requests for "/PageA.html"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^PageA\.html$ /PageB [R=302,L]

# 2. Rewrite "/PageB" back to the actual filesystem path
RewriteRule ^PageB$ PageA.html [L]
```

Generally, the external redirect should always go *before* the internal rewrite.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. Very informative.